# Microsoft.Office.Interop IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, excel-interop, indexoutofrangeexception

The below IndexOutOfRangeException is not letting my code run (it compiles). While I understand this kind of exception (array indexes etc) the issue is, what I am trying to do is simply update the String subsection2 with the value in cell B[excelrow]. For some reason, there is an index out of bounds exception which to me does not make sense. Neither subsection2 or excelrow is part of an array. The only array I can think of is the excel array, but excelrow is an integer with value of 3, it should updated to row B3, and so on. (I've even tried updating with B3 directly and I get the same error).

To help you out further with context, this method called createsource takes as input the excel spreadsheet and the total rows in that sheet. It does the below code to output a 2D array containing in the first dimension the excel index of each new order (each different customer), and the 2nd dimension is the number of items ordered per customer.

The method for the code is below:

private int[,] createsource(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet, int totalRows)
        {

```
        String subsection = "";
        object subsection2 = "";
        int orders = 0;

        //figures out how many different pages there are going to be
        for (int n = 3; n < totalRows + 1; n++)
        {
            if (!(xlWorksheet.get_Range("B" + n.ToString()).Text == subsection))
            {
                subsection = xlWorksheet.get_Range("B" + n.ToString()).Text;
                orders++;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(orders.ToString());
        int[,] source = new int[orders, 2];

        int excelrow = 3;
        subsection2 = xlWorksheet.get_Range("B" + excelrow.ToString()).Text;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < orders + 1; i++)
        {
            int j = 1;
            if (excelrow == totalRows + 1)
            {
                break;
            }

 //Out of bounds exception is found in the below if statement updating subsection2:

            if (!(xlWorksheet.get_Range("B" + excelrow.ToString()).Text == subsection2))
            {
                source[i, 0] = excelrow;
                //MessageBox.Show(xlWorksheet.get_Range("B" + excelrow.ToString()).Text.ToString());
                subsection2 = xlWorksheet.get_Range("B" + excelrow.ToString()).Text;
                excelrow++;
            }

            for (int iter = 0; iter < 1;)
            {
                if (excelrow == totalRows + 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (xlWorksheet.get_Range("B" + excelrow.ToString()).Text == subsection2)
                {
                    excelrow++;
                    j++;
                }
                if (!(xlWorksheet.get_Range("C" + excelrow.ToString()).Text == subsection2))
                {
                    subsection2 = xlWorksheet.get_Range("C" + excelrow.ToString()).Text;
                    iter = 1;
                }
            }

            source[i, 1] = j;

        }

        MessageBox.Show(source[2, 0].ToString());
        return source;

    }
```

Comment: Get the value of `xlWorksheet.get_Range("B" + excelrow.ToString()).Text` in a new variable. Also, close your code in a `try/catch`. In the `catch` get the full description of the error: Example: `catch (Exception ex) {  string strError = ex.ToString(); }` and [edit] your question with the error's description.

Comment: Which **exact** line throws the exception?

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem.  You're declaring source as:

```
int[,] source = new int[orders, 2];
```

... okay, but look at your loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < orders + 1; i++)
```

... which later feeds into:

```
source[i, 0] = excelrow;
```

Okay, so if orders = 100, you've declared a 100 long array, going from 0-99.  Then your loop, you go from 0 to "less than 100+1", aka 0-100.  When you get to the last loop, you're using a value of i=100, and trying to put it into the array spot that doesn't exist.

You need to either decrease your loop by one, or increase your array size by 1.